# Determine step size for explicit Euler of complex system

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stability-in-odes

I have the following system

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{u}_1 \\
\dot{u}_2 \\
\vdots \\
\dot{u}_{999}
\end{bmatrix} = -\frac{1}{1000^2}\operatorname{tridiag}(-1,2,-1)\begin{bmatrix}
u_1 \\
u_2 \\
\vdots \\
u_{999}
\end{bmatrix}$$

where the tridiagonal matrix (call it $A$) has dimensions $999\times999$ and $u_1(0) = \dots u_{999}(0) = 1.$

I'm asked what time step I would choose when using the explicit Euler method. My initial thoughts were to consider stability and using the explicit euler method I obtain 
$$u_{n+1} = (I -\frac{h}{1000^2}A)u_n.$$
I know from before that the eigenvalues of $A$ is
$$-4\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi m}{2(M+1)}\right), \quad m=1,2,\dots,M$$
So I obtain the eigenvalues 
$$\lambda_m = 1 + \frac{4h}{1000^2}\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi m}{2(M+1)}\right)$$
which should be less than $1$ for stability which means but this is not possible for nonzero $h$. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have another look at your application of Euler's method. It appears you have the wrong sign.

Comment: @CarlChristian But the negative sign comes from the matrix? Is that still wrong?

Comment: Then the sign of the eigenvalues is wrong, $-\sin((k-1)a)+2\sin(ka)-\sin((k+1)a)=2(1-\cos(a)\sin(ka)=4\sin^2(a/2)\sin(ka)$ has positive sign in the eigenvalue $4\sin^2(a/2)$

Comment: How did you get the factor for your matrix? If your space interval is $[0,1]$ and you divide it into 1000 pieces, then $\Delta x=\frac1{1000}$ and the factor for the Laplace discretization is $\frac1{\Delta x^2}=1000^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the system of ordinary differential equations given by 
$$y'(t) = By(t)$$
where $B$ is a square matrix and $u$ is a compatible vector. Euler's method takes the form
$$u_{n+1} = u_n + hBu_n = (I + hB)u_n$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix of proper size. It follows that 
$$ u_n = (I + hB)^n u_0.$$
If the matrix $B$ is asymptotically stable, then the solution $y$ will decay to zero as $t$ tends to infinity. We desire that the computed solution $u$ exhibits the same behavior as $n$ tends to infinity. This is assured if the absolute value of the eigenvalues of the driving matrix, i.e., $G_h = I + hB$ are strictly less than unity.

In the case under discussion, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{999 \times 999}$ is the matrix
$$ B = -\frac{1}{1000^2} \operatorname{tridiag}(-1,2,-1) $$
This matrix has eigenvalues which are strictly negative.

---

In general, loop as much information as possible into your symbols and avoid carrying signs around unless you absolutely have to.